# enquire.js not working with mediaMatch and Respond.js IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery

My question was answered before for earlier versions of enquire.js and respond.js but it doesn't seem to work for me.
I am using enquire.js 2.1.2, mediaMatch 2.0.2 and Respond.js 1.4.2.
I am using a responsive slider and I need images for varying width an device-pixel-ratio.
At the momement I am only testing with one image - two sizes.
enquire.js works in firefox and chrome as long as I load Respond.js before mediaMach and enquire.js.
But it is not working in in IE8 - maybe that is not necessary anymore, but I would like a solution.
If I load Respond.js after mediaMatch IE8 doesn't recognize media queries.
If I load it before it accepts media queries, but in both cases enquire.js is not working.
As advised I am using a stripped version of Respond.js - without the mediaMatch polyfill.

I would be very grateful for help
mawgaw

```
My code - abbreviated:

<script>

    jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    enquire.register("screen and (max-width:660px)", [

    {

       match : function() {

     $( "#bild" ).html(image)
     }},

      {match : function() {

    function to append layer script to body
     }}
     ])

    .register("screen and (min-width:661px )", [

    {

       match : function() {

      $( "#bild" ).html(image)
       }},
      {match : function() {
      function to append layer script to body
     }}
     ]);
    })
    </script>
```